# How does Spark Streaming process multiple topic

Tags: spark-streaming

How does Spark process multiple Kafka topic at one Dstream ?

1.on by one in a row.

2.simultaneously (topic-partition per executor).

Answer (score 0):

In DirectStream method spark process Kafka data parallelly. i.e each executor core will pull data from corresponding kafka topic and partition.

Lets say you have 2 topics each with 3 partitions. And you have 3 executors each with 2 cores.

If you are reading from these 2 topics then spark will launch 1 job with 6 tasks (=6 cores) and each task pulls data from corresponding topic+partition. And all these tasks run parallelly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.was helpful